# How to attach VS2010 debugger to a SheepAop weaved assembly?

Tags: debugging, aop

I'm giving SheepAOP a go for a new project, but i'm hitting a point where i can't use the VS2010 debugger. The breakpoints are not recognised and it looks like the pdbs are out of sync with the weaved code.

I've tried it with the sample provided on the [SheepAOP website](http://sheepaspect.codeplex.com/), but no cigar there either.

Comment: Just to add that the discussion page on the project website is probably the best place to get an ear for any issues you have :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SheepAspect produces bytecodes that are specifically intended to maintain debuggability, but one thing that I find necessary is to make sure you turn on "Just My Code" in your VS debugging options. 
You could still reach your aspect code using breakpoint regardless of that option, but to make your F11(step-into) jump into your aspect, I find that "Just my code" option is required. Otherwise it will only jump thorugh your (original) code, skipping any injected aspect it may pass. (I was going to add this in the "debugging & unit-testing tips" section).

I've yet to investigate the root of this issue, but it seems to be a limitation within Visual Studio that seemingly just "gives up" to proceed further with the debugging whenever it runs into any instruction with no corresponding source-code. "Just my code" option prevents visual studio to get to that situation in the first place.

Let me know if that solves your problem.

(UPDATED to fix inaccurate explanation as per my comment below)

Comment: Apparently the "Just my code" option is enabled, but i can't get in debugging mode. I'll continue to look for it, but thanks :)

Comment: I'll look into this issue. Thanks for bringing it to my attention

Comment: I just investigated with the latest SheepAspect (nuget.org/List/Packages/SheepAspect), and debugging seems to all work fine. Pls give it a try and see if it's still not working for you. Regarding the "Just My Code" option, I described it wrongly above. If the option is disabled, you all your breakpoints DO still work perfectly. It's F11 that becomes slightly broken: it will only step into your actual code, doesn't jump into your aspect code unless you put breakpoints there. To make F11 step into your aspects without having to place any breakpoints on them, you need 'Just my code' enabled

Comment: By the way, the link was for the Preview-2 release, which is very recent, and is generally a lot more stable than the Preview-1. There are a lot of issues that have been addressed, and error handling is generally better and some implementation details have been improved, which might also affect your debugging experience. It also sets up your project automatically. So I highly recommend you to upgrade. The sample projects have also been updated

Comment: Well, looks like the latest version works perfectly now :) Thanks!